# Unable to insert data into link table in hibernate many to many

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Relations are like

- A project can have many employees.

on a JSP, On selecting a project, all employees are populated.
A text box for task.

Provide a task name for that selected project , select employee(s) for that task and save.

I am able to save task but not in link table.

Entity classes are,

Employee, Task, Project

**Employee**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="employee_id")
    private String employeeId;

    @Column(name="employee_name")
    private String employeeName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="employees")
    private Set<Task> tasks;
}
```

**Project**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Project")
public class Project implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    private int projectId;

    @Column(name = "project_name")
    private String projectName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "PROJECT_EMPLOYEE", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "project_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") })
    private Set<Employee> employees;

}
```

**Task**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Task")
public class Task implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "task_id")
    private int taskId;

    @Column(name = "task_details")
    private String taskDetails;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Date startDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private Date endDate;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", nullable = false)
    private Project project;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Task_Employee", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "task_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") })
    @Embedded
    private Set<Employee> employees;
}
```

*Not able to save into Task_Employee table.*

**Dao code:**

From jsp, I am getting all string values and creating task object like this, empView is the view object getting from JSP page and creating Task object to save in dao.

```
Set<Employee> empSet = new HashSet<Employee>();
for(String employeeId : empView.getEmployees()) {
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setEmployeeId(employeeId);
    //emp.setEmployeeName("aaa");
    //emp.setProject(new Project(empView.getProjectId()));
    empSet.add(emp);
}

return new Task(0, empView.getTaskDesc(), new Project(empView.getProjectId()), toDate(empView.getStartDate()),
                toDate(empView.getEndDate()), empSet);
```

**Save the above returned task object.**

```
sessionFactory.openSession().save(task);
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the error you're getting ?

Comment: No error. only Task table is getting data inserted. but not the Task_Employee table. I think i have issue with the Task object creation before saving into db. Not sure. Thanks for replying Prabhat

Comment: show your jsp snippet for mapping `employees`?